# LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'. with CEUR style

Tags: floats

I am getting an error `LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'`, when I try to fix a figure in some place. I have included `\usepackage{float}` as suggested by [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/LaTeX_Error%3A_Unknown_float_option_%60H%27), but I am still unable to resolve this. [CEUR](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-XXX/CEURART.zip) package information available is [here](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-XXX/CEURART.zip).

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{ceurart}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{breaklines=true}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\copyrightyear{2021}
\copyrightclause{some cc}
\conference{some conference}

\title{some title}

\author[1]{Auth1}[]
\address[1]{add1}


\maketitle

\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bEGiY}
  \caption{some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image can be found here [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEGiY.png)

Comment: float isn't compatible with all classes, simply not using H is usually the best plan. note for examples here I would avoid minted unless asking about that as it forces people to use shell-escape, and using shell-escape on code copied from random internet sites is not recommended. Also you can use `example-image` as the image, as it is generally available for tests.

Comment: Apparently the class make some changes on how floats behave, I would say in a first view that the `float` package is incompatible with this class

Comment: Have you asked the template maintainer? Unrelated: the template source code on Overleaf mentions, as one of the conditions of use, that modifying the template is not allowed; and the template's instructions about figures is minimal. This suggests to me that guidance from the template maintainer is the optimal solution method, so the template can be modified (or not), and instructions added (or not) about forcing figure placement.